# Exponential of a matrix Vs. General Solution for ODE linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the first differential equation class I took we would solve linear systems of the for $y'=Ax$ using the general solution form. ie. $C_1e^{\lambda_1 t}x_1+C_2e^{\lambda_2 t}x_2$ where the lambdas are the eigenvalues and the $x_i$ are eigenvectors.

I am now in my second ODE course and we are now using the matrix exponential to solve the same system! We are using that $y=y_0e^{A(t-t_0)}$. What I don't understand:

1) How are these two methods related?

2) Why would anyone want to use the matrix exponential? It is so much more difficult!

I have asked my professor and numerous other students and no one can give me a good answer. I am hoping someone can help me out on here.

Thanks!

Comment: They're related by the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$, as you say. (Compute what the matrix exponential does when applied to eigenvectors.) The matrix exponential is useful for when $A$ is not diagonalizable, and also for various theoretical results. This should be explained in your textbook; if not, find a better textbook.

Comment: Could you recommend a textbook? I am using Sideris and I really don't care for it. It is very brief.

Comment: Even if A is not diagonalizeable we can still use the general solution form couldn't we?

Comment: This is explained reasonably well in chapter 9 of *Fundamentals of Differential Equations* by Nagle, Saff, and Snider.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out.

Comment: actually its impossible to calculate the matrix exponential analytically for greater dimension. But it doesnt depend on the diagonaliziable property like you said + its easier to work with it in certain proofs.

Comment: If $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue, then your general solution is no longer $y=c_{1}e^{\lambda_{1}t}+c_{2}e^{\lambda_{2}t}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwSk9M5lJx4 provides a great video about this.